# How to use more than one network to get ICE candidates with ion-sfu (pion)

Tags: go, webrtc, sfu

I'm using an ion-sfu (and signaling) on a AWS instance running on its private network 10.0.0.160

This instance also have an elastic IP address 207.61.171.104

We access that SFU with a VPN that have access to the private network and also through a carrier gateway the elastic IP address.

To make it work on the elastic IP network, we add its IP in the setting:

```
nat1to1=["207.61.171.104"]
```

but when we do this the other network 10.0.0.x are no more able to establish a peer connection.

and when adding both to the list like this:

```
nat1to1 = ["10.0.0.160","207.61.171.104"]
```

then both are not working.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have both network peers to be able to connect to the sfu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting is exposing [SetNAT1To1IPs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pion/webrtc/v3#SettingEngine.SetNAT1To1IPs) from pion/webrtc.

SetNAT1To1IPs comes with two modes. `ICECandidateTypeHost` which replaces all your private IPs with one of your choosing (what it is doing right now) or `ICECandidateTypeSrflx` which just appends an IP of your choosing.

I think we should add a `nat1to1_mode` to ion-sfu. Where you can choose `ICECandidateTypeHost` or `ICECandidateTypeSrflx`. If you are interested would love to help you make that PR! You can try changing the code easily today [here](https://github.com/pion/ion-sfu/blob/e42ee589aab5c25a33fa6bae4b00e6812e97d035/pkg/sfu/sfu.go#L165)

If you have more questions happy to chat here or on [Pion Slack](https://pion.ly/slack)

Comment: How those settings should be used in my situation to make both network working at the same time?

Comment: Adding a line of code to add a ICECandidateTypeSrflx with the elastic IP solved this issue. @seandubois will look at making the change.